# I recently started to self learn python and I'm really confused about the terminology in the "classes" section

Tags: python, terminology

Is the class (method?) just to customize a new type?
Is an instance just a particular variable of a new customized type?
Really confused about "attribute" because there are many different opinions like [here](https://www.py4e.com/html3/14-objects) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html).

```
class PartyAnimal:
   x = 0

   def party(self) :
     self.x = self.x + 1
     print("So far",self.x)

an = PartyAnimal()
```

btw how's the `self.x = self.x + 1` work here?
I appreciate your help and pardon me for the broken English.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the `class` (method?) just to customize a new type?

A `class` is the framework for an object. An object is an instance of the `class`:

```py
class PartyAnimal:
    ...

# `an` is an instance of PartyAnimal
an = PartyAnimal()
```

A method is a function within the `class`. In your example, `def party(self)` is a method of `PartyAnimal`

---

> Really confused about "attribute"

An attribute of a `class` is the `class.something` thing.

The attribute of your `PartyAnimal` `class` is the `self.x` part, where `x` is an attribute of `PartyAnimal`. You can get the value of `x` for each instance with:

```
class PartyAnimal:
   x = 0

   def party(self) :
     self.x = self.x + 1
     print("So far",self.x)
```

```
>>> an = PartyAnimal()
>>> an.x
0
# Then run the method
>>> an.party()
'So far 1'
>>> an.x
1
```

> Docs - https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-attribute

---

> btw how's the `self.x = self.x + 1` work here?

You're adding `1` to the attribute `x`. Same as `x += 1` if you weren't using classes

---

I recommend reading [the w3 article on classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp). It's really good

Answer (score 0):

Putting in very easy words, any variables that are defined inside a class are called attributes. An instance of a class is a copy of that particular class.

When you instantiate a class `PartyAnimal()`, a copy of it is created. You assign it to a variable of the same type `an`.

```
an = PartyAnimal()
```

Now, let's refer to `an` as an instance of the class `PartyAnimal()`. `an` contains an attribute `x` which is initially set to the value `0`. It can be accessed using the `.` operator.

```
print(an.x) # output: 0
```

By default, attributes of a class in python are `public`. Meaning they can be accessed outside of the class. If you want to increment the value of `x` by `1`, you can do it by:

```
an.x = an.x + 1
print(an.x) # output: 1
```

Now, talking about the method `party()`, which takes the parameter `self`. `self` represents the instance of the class. In `party()`, the value of `x` is incremented. To know that we are referring to the variable `x` of that instance and not any other `x` (sometimes the variable with the name `x` is passed into the function), we use `self`.

Refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp) to know more about `self`.

Answer (score 0):

[The first link you posted](https://www.py4e.com/html3/14-objects) explains most of your questions...

Explaining what methods are - they're functions *inside* the object and class:

> An object can contain a number of **functions** (which we call **methods**)

[The second link you posted](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) confirms this:

> **Method**: A **function** which is defined inside a class body. If called as an attribute of an instance of that class, the method will get the instance object as its first argument (which is usually called self). See function and nested scope.

---

Explaining what classes are...

> the `class` keyword defines a **template** indicating what data and code will be contained in each object of type `PartyAnimal`. The class is like a cookie cutter and the objects created using the class are the cookies.

> `counts = dict()`
> Here we instruct Python to construct an object using the `dict` **template** (already present in Python), return the instance of dictionary, and assign it to the variable counts.

It compares `dict` and `PartyAnimal` as both templates, both types of objects.

---

Explaining what attributes are - they're data *inside* the object and class:

> We call **data** items that are part of the object **attributes**.

> **Attribute**: A **value** associated with an object which is referenced by name using dotted expressions.

---

Explaining that object and instance are interchangeable and that they are assigned to variables...

> `an = PartyAnimal()` This is where we instruct Python to construct (i.e., create) an **object or instance** of the class `PartyAnimal`.

> Python constructs the object with the right data and methods and returns the object which is then assigned to the **variable** `an`.

> When the `PartyAnimal` class is used to construct an object, the **variable `an` is used to point to that object**.

---

Explaining your question about `self.x = self.x+1`...

> When the `party` method is called, **the first parameter** (which we call by convention **`self`**) **points to the particular instance of the `PartyAnimal` object** that `party` is called from. Within the `party` method, we see the line:

> `self.x = self.x + 1`

> This syntax using the dot operator is saying **"the `x` within `self`"**. Each time `party()` is called, the internal `x` value is incremented by 1 and the value is printed out.

---

I could not find conflicting information between the two links you posted.